# Заменить проверку на null, на использование Optional

Tags: java

Есть такой кусок кода

```
Integer page;
if (request.queryParams("size") != null) {
    page = Integer.parseInt(Optional.of(request.queryParams("size")).orElse(null));
} else {
    page = null;
}

Integer limit;
if (request.queryParams("limit") != null) {
    limit = Integer.parseInt(Optional.of(request.queryParams("limit")).orElse(null));
} else {
    limit = null;
}
```

Как его изменить, что бы убрать эти проверки на null, с помощью `Optional`?
Если пишу так, то не работает, все равно получается `NullPointerException`, если нет "size" или "limit"

```
Integer page = Integer.parseInt(Optional.of(request.queryParams("size")).orElse(null));
Integer limit = Integer.parseInt(Optional.of(request.queryParams("limit")).orElse(null));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
page = Optinal
         .ofNullable(request.queryParams("size"))
         .filter(v -> v.matches("\\d+"))
         .map(Integer::parseInt)
         .orElse(1);
```

Comment: это 8 ява? да :??

Comment: @elik да, `Optional` появился в 8-й.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev официально да. А так в Guava ж был https://github.com/google/guava/blob/d9f088a61c80fa47d09ccf05a8c3608a47c5e4c0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а что значит строка которую вы добавили? .filter(v -> v.matches("\\d+"))

Comment: Отбросить нечисловые значения. Чтобы, если в `size` кто-нибудь передаст строку "abc", не вылетело исключение.